# IEnumerable - implementing using GetEnumerator from local variable

Tags: c#, ienumerable

I'm newb with generics/iterators/enumerators etc.

I have code, it keeps field number (int) and error mesages (List string) for each field:

```
  public class ErrorList : IEnumerable // ?
  {
        private Dictionary <int, List<string>> errorList;

        // ...
  }
```

How to make this class work with foreach loop? I wanna use GetEnumerator form Dictionary, but how should i do this?

Comment: What do you want to enumerate?  The messages?  The error numbers?  A combination of both?

Comment: Edited: I wanna use Dictionary enumerator (GetEnumerator).

Comment: BTW: errorList is not a local variable, it's a private field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply provide a public `GetEnumerator` method:

```
public class ErrorList
{
    private Dictionary<int, List<string>> errorList = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

    ... some methods that fill the errorList field

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<int, List<string>>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return errorList.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

and now assuming you have an instance of ErrorList:

```
var errors = new ErrorList();
```

you can loop through them:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<string>> item in errors)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: No need of an interface. All that the `foreach` loop needs is a public method called `GetEnumerator` that returns an `IEnumerator`.

Comment: Yay, u solve it. Now I understand this method declaration w/o interface inheritance.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov It doesn't even have to return `IEnumerator`. [It just needs](https://gist.github.com/2173295) to return something with an `Current` property and `MoveNext` method.

Comment: @phoog I would typically put the interface in myself, I just find it interesting that `foreach` relies entirely on duck typing.

Comment: @vcsjones yes, I agree it's interesting.  It's mainly a relic of the pre-generics world where duck typing was necessary to avoid a boxing penalty for collections of value-type elements.  It's also worth noting that implementing the interface is necessary for a custom collection to work with linq.

Answer (score 1):

Dictionary implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, so this works:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<Int, List<String>> kvp in errorList) {
    var idx = kvp.Key;
    var vals = kvp.Value;
    // ... do whatever here
}
```

Comment: Though I’d definitely stick a `var` on that `foreach`, as in `foreach (var kvp in errorList) { ... }`

Comment: Sure- I did it this way intentionally to show the type of the loop variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply return `errorList.GetEnumerator()`.